# Вывод числа состоящего только из четных цифр Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Обучаюсь на начальном этапе Python, не знаю как подойти к решению такой задачи:

> Выведите на экран все числа в интервале от 100 до 400 включительно, каждое из которых состоит только из **четных цифр** (например 200, 260, 282 и т.д.).

Делаю список цифр от 100 до 400, но дальше как вывести именно только значения, состоящие из четных цифр не знаю..

```
a = list(range(100, 400))
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    b = a[i]
    i += 1
print(a)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать дальше, желательно максимально доступно)

Comment: *Только примечание:* Вообще **не надо превращать объект `range` в список:** `list(range(100, 400))` это плохая практика, достаточно использовать `range(100, 400)`.

Answer (score 6):

Как вариант

```
for num in range(100, 401):
    if all(int(digit) % 2 == 0 for digit in str(num)):
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 4):

Решение через множества. Создаем множество четных цифр, каждое число раскладываем на цифры и проверяем, является ли множество четных цифр надмножеством для цифр этого числа.

```
chet = set('02468')
for num in range(100,401):
    if chet.issuperset(str(num)):
        print(num)
```

Вариант без множеств и преобразования в строку. Разбираем в цикле каждое число из диапазона, проверяя остаток от деления на 2 и на каждой итерации деля на 10, чтобы проверить следующую цифру. Если находим нечетное число, происходит досрочный выход из `while` и ничего не печатается. Если цикл отработал полностью (выхода по `break` не было), срабатывает `else:` и число печатается.

```
for num in range(100, 401):
    x = num
    while x > 0:
        if x % 2 != 0:
            break
        x //= 10
    else:
        print(num)
```

```
200
202
204
...
286
288
400
```

Comment: ``range(100, 401, 2)`` чтобы не проверять заведомо неподходящие числа

Comment: @Эникейщик, тогда уж `range(200, 401, 2)` потому что в `1xx` ни одна из цифр не подходит

Comment: @Grundy да, точно!

Answer (score 4):

Зачем вообще проходить, проверять и отсеивать неподходящие числа? Просто работаем в пятеричной системе.

```
for i in range(25,51):
    print(i//25*2,i//5%5*2,i%5*2,sep='')
```

Допустимые цифры 0,2,4,6,8 можно рассматривать как удвоенные 0,1,2,3,4.  А такой (и не более!) набор цифр соответствует пятеричной системе счисления. В этой системе диапазон пятеричных чисел будет непрерывным `100,101,102,103,104,110,111...144,200` (а в десятичном виде это 25..50). Просто перебираем их подряд, и каждую цифру (выделяемую с помощью целочисленного деления и взятия остатка) этих пятеричных чисел при выводе умножаем на 2.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подробнее объяснить как это работает?

Comment: @Be3y4uu_K0T Готово

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(100, 401):
   if (i % 10) % 2 == 0 and ((i // 10) % 10) % 2 == 0 and (i // 100) % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Вывод:

200
202
204
206
208
220
222
224
226
228
240
242
244
246
248
260
262
264
266
268
280
282
284
286
288
400

Если 4 % 2 = 0 остаток от деления  равен 0, число четное.

Разделить разряды числа можно следующим образом,
число 123:

```
123 % 10 = 3 т.е. Последнее число
(123 // 10) % 10 = 2 Среднее число
123 // 100 = 1 первое число.
```

Каждое число проверяем на четность если все четные, записываем.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось как-то так:

```
for i in range(100, 401):
     var1, var2,var3 = str(i)[0], str(i)[1], str(i)[2]
     if int(var1) % 2 == 0 and int(var2) % 2 == 0 and int(var3) % 2 == 0:
          print(f'{var1 + var2 + var3}')
```

Answer (score 1):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1Vw8jAQEfB0ABEApmaVlwKCiAVlQgVFToKFdqGEAVgeYiKKoSKSh2FSqAKoAKovIJCQVFmXolGleb//wA)

```
for x in range(200, 1000, 200):
  for y in range(x, x+100, 20):
    for z in range(y, y+10, 2):
      print(z)
```

Тьфу, до 400, а не до 1000. Тогда так: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##Tco7DoAgEAXAnlO8EiLFolYmHsbCD4kshliAl0f8JNpOZkv74rnJebUOPVoyQkw@IMIywsDzKGsiDWdZlqJhiEhpFFSdAK6bvht/M1bmrfd87vHd9Lup3Ku@E9iC5V0eKucT)

```
lim = 401

for x in range(200, min(lim, 1000), 200):
  for y in range(x, min(lim, x+100), 20):
    for z in range(y, min(lim, y+10), 2):
      print(z)
```

Comment: в почему тогда просто три цикла от 2х до 10 ?

Comment: @Grundy, где и что?

Answer (score 0):

В строчке

> i += 1

1 поменяй на 2, но это конкретно в этом контексте, так оно просто отобразит числа через одно, то есть 100, 102, 104, и так далее, пропуская при этом 101, 103, и т.д.

Comment: а 300 отобразит?

Comment: Да, отобразит, почему нет?

Comment: Не должен, потому что `3` - нечетная цифра

Comment: 296, 298, 300, 302, ..., 398, 400

Comment: Цифра, это не число, это всё равно что сказать что оно не отобразит 100, потому что "1 это нечетная цифра"

Comment: Совет полезный, потому что сокращает количество проверок в два раза. но ответом не является, т.к. задачу не решает

Answer (score 0):

Для `while` вот вариант решения.
Создайте `a` как пустой список и в цикле `while` методом `append` заполните его:

```
a = []
b = 100
n = 400
i = 0

while i <= n - b:
    elem = b + i
    if (elem % 10) % 2 == 0 and ((elem // 10) % 10) % 2 == 0 and (elem // 100) % 2 == 0:
        a.append(elem)
    i += 2
print(a)
```

Comment: 0xdb, спасибо за правку, я тут человек новый, не знаю всех деталей правильного написания вопросов и ответов, просто хотел написать код, правильно решающий задачу.

Comment: Этот вариант ничем принципиально не отличается  от ответа Oopss, только цикл for заменён на неуместный здесь while ,и условие зачем-то запутано.

Comment: MBo
 Автор вопроса начал с while, как вариант, я счёл нужным именно так ответить и кстати, сам такую задачу решал, когда в домашнем задании требовался именно while, хотя с for короче, вестимо.

Comment: В моём таком же домашнем задании не было list(range), в остальном была свобода для творчества и да, я скопировал if у другого ответившего, мой вариант был другим.

Answer (score 0):

```
evens = "0 2 4 6 8".split()

for i in range(200, 401, 2):
    hundreds, tens, ones = str(i)
    if (hundreds in evens and
        tens in evens and ones in evens):
        print(i)
```

---

*Обяснение:*

1. **evens, hudreds, tens, ones**    по-русски    **четные, сотни, десятки, единицы.**
2. `"0 2 4 6 8".split()` — то же самое как `['0', '2', '4', '6', '8']`, но короче.
3. `range(200, 401, 2)` - достаточно начинать с `200`, потому первая цифра не может быть `1`, и тестировать только каждое второе, т. е. четное число.
4. `str(i)` - это итеровательный объект (строка из трея букв), значит, мы можем из него получить отдельные буквы распаковкой `hundreds, tens, ones = str(i)`.

Comment: первая не может быть 3 поэтому все 3х тоже стоит выкинуть

Comment: @Grundy, я знаю, но я хочу, чтобы код был красивым и понятным. Проверка 50 лишних чисел здесь не играет никакую роль.

Comment: тогда и вычеркивание первой сотни не особо важно :)

Comment: @Grundy, вы правы, но написать **200** вместо **100** не делает код более сложным (как бы это было в случае пропуска третьей сотни). Оптимизация ценой замены одной цифры. :-)

Comment: Делает, просто потому, что теряется связь с задачей, в которой указано именно (100:400)

Comment: @Grundy, не более сложным, хотя менее понятным. В том вы правы, потому я написал обьяснение. Но и почему я решил **200** вместо **100**? Чтобы избежать комментариев типа *«почему **100** а не **200**?»* По-видимому, я тем не избежал обратных комментариев. :-( Я предлагаю компромисс - **150**. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

А такого ещё никто не предлагал: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##TZDBbsMgEETv@xVztFsSQeJDVZX@COKQCtygIozAUsnXO@CKNMeZebur2Xhbr0s4v8W0bcbO@F4Gz5DGdwIKMxkSnCl1YpPWVL3fq/MW5SM1AHAzCj4l/J8Ebs56g0K7nJcEAxdgcs/rgFFCd1mP4FVWi@uH03IcJMTD@Ur28kP0FEtM1OcrOuHlf4f12fb9JtiyVtpkdRC6EhUUnJ5PN6LT@XiJ0QYzqN1mOOuRqNUorUZ9zolzhomL/UExubAOZdy2Ow)

```
def go(l, r):
  x,ds = 0,[[2,4]]

  while x < r:
    if x >= l:
      yield x

    for d in ds:
      if d[1]:
        x += d[0]
        d[1] -= 1
        break

      d[1] = 4
      x -= 4 * d[0]
    else:
      dnext = ds[-1][0] * 10
      x += dnext
      ds.append([dnext, 3])

for x in go(200, 401):
  print(x)
```

Comment: ты б хоть описание написал что тут за магия происходит

Comment: @Grundy, смахивает на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1558208/178988, но в ручном режиме...